# log4net log being created but remaining empty

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, log4net

I'm attempting to use [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/).  When I fire up the app it creates the log file, but no matter how many times I call `Log.Info("Application Started");` it remains empty.  I've researched the first two pages that google returns and my code seems to match all examples.

Code:

```
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]

namespace Generator
{
     public class Run
     {

       private static readonly log4net.ILog Log =
       log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public List<BILL_RUN> PerformBillRun()
        {
             XmlConfigurator.Configure();

             Log.Info("Application Started");
             var enabled = Log.IsInfoEnabled; //This is true
        }

     }

}
```

app.config

```xml
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="log-files.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="All" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Any pointers as to what may be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This always happens to me...as soon as I post the question.

It turns out my `<configSections></configSections>` tags weren't directly a child to `<configuration>` meaning that the config wouldn't be picked up (I assume), and because log4net swallows all exceptions this only manifested itself further into my app.

Logging is working fine now.

Comment: It's also useful to add `<log4net debug="true">` to the opening tag of your config to see a lot more info, assuming you have a console to see the output)